# Formula to find 2nd lowest value with additional criteria

Tags: excel, excel-2007, formula, vba

In D1 of my worksheet, I want the name of the worker with the 2nd to last (2nd oldest) assignment date/time.

Column A lists Employees
Column B lists the last Date/Time a task was Assigned

```
Column A    Column B
Betty    6/5/14 2:45 PM
Bob     5/31/14 9:38 AM
Connie  6/7/14 10:25 PM
Dan     6/3/14 2:05 AM
Earl    6/3/14 4:45 PM
```

In this case, D1 would show Dan

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by using this in D1:

=INDEX(A2:A6,MATCH(SMALL(B2:B6,2),B2:B6,0))

SMALL will allow you to find the second oldest value

MATCH will help you find its index in the array

INDEX will find this index value in the first column